# what is the time complexity for this function?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

This should be simple but I'm having trouble trying to find the time complexity for my `printRow()` function.

My guess is that since `printChar()` is O(n), `printRow()` must be O(a + b).

I'm not sure if that is correct or incorrect. Any help with an explanation would be awesome!

```
// prints a row consisting of " " a times and "*" b times...
// a and can be <, =, or > b
// complexity: O(?)
function printRow(a, b) {
     var str = '';
     // prints " " a times
     str += printChar(" ", a);
     // prints "*" b times
     str += printChar("*", b);
     return str;
}

// prints char n times
// complexity: O(n) because of the for loop
function printChar(char, n) {
    var str = '';
    for (var i=0; i<n; i++) {
        str += char;
    }
    return str;
}
```

Comment: you are correct, if the += operator for strings is O(1). In fact this is a big assumption that will often not hold.

Comment: Henry's correct, and `+=` for strings has 2 issues: 1) most implementations need to grow memory for the string occasionally, and that can mean copying all existing text to the start of a new, larger buffer; still - if the string grows by a proportion of its too-small size, it won't affect the overall big-O complexity; 2) *some* languages (e.g. C) use NUL-terminated strings, for them each append could involve a search for the current end (a la `strlen`) - which is O(n) (there are efficient ways to keep track of the current end in C, such as moving a pointer along as you append).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A huge part of this is the implementation of +=.

In the worst likely case, to make the longer string, a memory allocation large enough for the result string must be done. This is the followed by copying the entire content of the strings to the new location.

Copying the entire string like this is an O(n) operation. Doing this whilst you append every character, one at a time would make the whole algorithm O(n^2).

Best case: you preallocate the total space needed and then fill it with the data you need. This is O(n).

In between there is a common O(n) strategy in which the space allocated to the string is possibly larger than it needs, and as you grow it, it fills that up. When required more space is allocated proportional to the current size (say doubling the size), the current string is copied to there and then the process can continue.

Each expansion is expensive as before, but they are also significantly less frequent and do give an amortized O(n) run time.